# Full width header responsive image, with left & right overflow

Tags: css

I want to place a full width image (somethink like a header or slider) but I want to show only the center of the image, UNLESS the viewport would be so big than the image had to be enlarged.

Some detailed examples:

1. My image is 2000x200px
2. In a screen of 1600px width I want to show the central 1600px of my image, no resize.
3. In a screen of 450px I want to show the central 1600px of my image, but shrink (resized-down)
4. In a screen of 1900px I want to show the central 1900px of my image, no resize.
5. In a screen of 2500px I want to show the full width 2000px of my image, of course, enlarged.

What I have so far:

- Make a responsive image is quite easy

```css
#header-img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

But it always shows the full image. There are a left and a right chunk I don't want to show unless the resolution of the client screen would be really big.

- On the other hand, get the "overflow" behaviour could be done setting the image as background of a div, and setting his *background-size* property to *cover*, but it's not responsive.

```html
<div style="background-image: url(header.jpg); background-size: cover; background-position: center; height: 200px" />
```

I need the two behaviours. Perhaps I need media-queries, but I'm trying to avoid it. I don't want any javascript code neither, only CSS.

I have seen this behaviour in some pages, but I can't find any at the moment.

EDIT: A picture speaks a thousand words

http://tomascrespo.sofiytommy.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/pregunta.jpg

Observe that numbers 7 and 8 are only showed in ultra wide screen

Comment: Can you add a fiddle?

Comment: Media queries are CSS, not JS

Comment: I know media queries are CSS. They are my last option, but really, I don't know how to accomplish this even with media queries

Comment: I've added an image to explain the problem. I can't add a fiddle because I dont't have nothing to put on that fiddle

Comment: You should solve it using media queries. I think this article will solve a lot of problems: https://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/